# Cascade Shadow Map Problems DirectX 11

Tags: directx11, sharpdx, shadow-mapping

So after fixing all my lighting and shadow problems that my new terrain system showed me that I had I have an issue with my shadow maps, I have had it since my XNA days but because of my world setup, field of view and no shadow jittering fix I couldn't really see it.

I'm 90% sure its to do with the way I fix the shadow jittering, this peace of code is really old and I have never really been able to fix it. It comes from [this page](https://jcoluna.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/xna-light-pre-pass-cascade-shadow-maps/) and I never really did much with it other than drop it in and it worked so I moved on to other parts of the engine.

Here is a pic so u can see what is going on, easier than you guys trying to work out what "a strange black peace of my shadow map".
[image]

It looks to me like there is a problem with the way the frustum is clipped but I'm not really sure so here is the light view projection code with the jitter fix, if I turn the jitter fix off then it fixes the problem but I'm left with jittery shadows.

VB.net

```
Private Function CreateLightViewProjectionMatrix(CASCADE_SHADOW_RESOLUTION As Single, lightDir As Vector3, minZ As Single, maxZ As Single, index As Integer, ByRef _Camera As Camera, frustumCornersWS As Vector3(), frustumCornersVS As Vector3(), _directionalClippingPlanes As Plane()) As Matrix


    Dim splitFrustumCornersVS As Vector3() = New Vector3(7) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        splitFrustumCornersVS(i) = frustumCornersVS(i + 4) * (minZ / _Camera.FarClip)
    Next

    For i As Integer = 4 To 7
        splitFrustumCornersVS(i) = frustumCornersVS(i) * (maxZ / _Camera.FarClip)
    Next

    Dim cameraMat As Matrix = _Camera.Transform


    For i As Integer = 0 To frustumCornersWS.Length - 1
        Vector3.Transform(splitFrustumCornersVS(i), cameraMat, frustumCornersWS(i))
    Next


    Dim cameraUpVector As Vector3 = Vector3.Up
    If Math.Abs(Vector3.Dot(cameraUpVector, lightDir)) > 0.9F Then
        cameraUpVector = Vector3.ForwardRH
    End If

    Dim lightRotation As Matrix = Matrix.LookAtRH(Vector3.Zero, -lightDir, cameraUpVector)


    For i As Integer = 0 To frustumCornersWS.Length - 1
        Vector3.Transform(frustumCornersWS(i), lightRotation, frustumCornersWS(i))
    Next


    Dim mins As Vector3 = frustumCornersWS(0), maxes As Vector3 = frustumCornersWS(0)
    For i As Integer = 1 To frustumCornersWS.Length - 1
        Dim p As Vector3 = frustumCornersWS(i)
        If p.X < mins.X Then
            mins.X = p.X
        End If
        If p.Y < mins.Y Then
            mins.Y = p.Y
        End If
        If p.Z < mins.Z Then
            mins.Z = p.Z
        End If
        If p.X > maxes.X Then
            maxes.X = p.X
        End If
        If p.Y > maxes.Y Then
            maxes.Y = p.Y
        End If
        If p.Z > maxes.Z Then
            maxes.Z = p.Z
        End If
    Next


    Dim minsVS As Vector3 = splitFrustumCornersVS(0), maxesVS As Vector3 = splitFrustumCornersVS(0)
    For i As Integer = 1 To splitFrustumCornersVS.Length - 1
        Dim p As Vector3 = splitFrustumCornersVS(i)
        If p.X < minsVS.X Then
            minsVS.X = p.X
        End If
        If p.Y < minsVS.Y Then
            minsVS.Y = p.Y
        End If
        If p.Z < minsVS.Z Then
            minsVS.Z = p.Z
        End If
        If p.X > maxesVS.X Then
            maxesVS.X = p.X
        End If
        If p.Y > maxesVS.Y Then
            maxesVS.Y = p.Y
        End If
        If p.Z > maxesVS.Z Then
            maxesVS.Z = p.Z
        End If
    Next
    Dim _lightBox As New BoundingBox(mins, maxes)


    If fixShadowJittering Then

        Dim diagonalLength As Single = (frustumCornersWS(0) - frustumCornersWS(6)).Length()

        Dim worldsUnitsPerTexel As Single = diagonalLength / CType(CASCADE_SHADOW_RESOLUTION , Single)
        Dim vBorderOffset As Vector3 = (New Vector3(diagonalLength, diagonalLength, diagonalLength) - (_lightBox.Maximum - _lightBox.Minimum)) * 0.5F
        _lightBox.Maximum += vBorderOffset
        _lightBox.Minimum -= vBorderOffset

        _lightBox.Minimum /= worldsUnitsPerTexel
        _lightBox.Minimum.X = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Minimum.X), Single)
        _lightBox.Minimum.Y = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Minimum.Y), Single)
        _lightBox.Minimum.Z = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Minimum.Z), Single)
        _lightBox.Minimum *= worldsUnitsPerTexel

        _lightBox.Maximum /= worldsUnitsPerTexel
        _lightBox.Maximum.X = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Maximum.X), Single)
        _lightBox.Maximum.Y = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Maximum.Y), Single)
        _lightBox.Maximum.Z = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Maximum.Z), Single)
        _lightBox.Maximum *= worldsUnitsPerTexel
    End If

    Dim boxSize As Vector3 = _lightBox.Maximum - _lightBox.Minimum
    If boxSize.X = 0 OrElse boxSize.Y = 0 OrElse boxSize.Z = 0 Then
        boxSize = Vector3.One
    End If
    Dim halfBoxSize As Vector3 = boxSize * 0.5F

         Dim lightPosition As Vector3 = _lightBox.Minimum + halfBoxSize
    lightPosition.Z = _lightBox.Minimum.Z

          lightPosition = Vector3.Transform(lightPosition, Matrix.Invert(lightRotation))

           Dim lightView As Matrix = Matrix.LookAtRH(lightPosition, lightPosition - lightDir, cameraUpVector)


    Dim lightProjection As Matrix = Matrix.OrthoRH(boxSize.X, boxSize.Y, -boxSize.Z, 0)

    Dim lightDirVS As Vector3 = Vector3.TransformNormal(-lightDir, _Camera.EyeTransform)

    Return lightView * lightProjection
End Function
```

Just the jitter fixing code:

```
   If fixShadowJittering Then

        Dim diagonalLength As Single = (frustumCornersWS(0) - frustumCornersWS(6)).Length()

        Dim worldsUnitsPerTexel As Single = diagonalLength / CType(CASCADE_SHADOW_RESOLUTION , Single)
        Dim vBorderOffset As Vector3 = (New Vector3(diagonalLength, diagonalLength, diagonalLength) - (_lightBox.Maximum - _lightBox.Minimum)) * 0.5F
        _lightBox.Maximum += vBorderOffset
        _lightBox.Minimum -= vBorderOffset

        _lightBox.Minimum /= worldsUnitsPerTexel
        _lightBox.Minimum.X = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Minimum.X), Single)
        _lightBox.Minimum.Y = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Minimum.Y), Single)
        _lightBox.Minimum.Z = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Minimum.Z), Single)
        _lightBox.Minimum *= worldsUnitsPerTexel

        _lightBox.Maximum /= worldsUnitsPerTexel
        _lightBox.Maximum.X = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Maximum.X), Single)
        _lightBox.Maximum.Y = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Maximum.Y), Single)
        _lightBox.Maximum.Z = CType(Math.Floor(_lightBox.Maximum.Z), Single)
        _lightBox.Maximum *= worldsUnitsPerTexel
    End If
```